# debian 10.3 - Network goes down when bringing up br0

Tags: debian, networking

I have a server at home running debian 10.3. I want to use this to run some virtual machines using KVM. I have been following the setup in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-kvm-server-debian-linux-9-headless-server/

When I try to bring up the bridged interface, things got weird. After removing the comments prepended with a single #, I got it up by running ifup br0. After a little while, the eth0 interface on the same machine stopped working. I could not reach it from the outside or reach anything from that machine. At the end I had to reboot it. I got some error messages on network not working (sorry, I didn't exactly what) and I have to remove the br0 config file to get it up with working network. When I put the br0 config back in place and got the interface up, exactly the same thing happened again. What am I doing wrong?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.99
```

This works fine and I get the routing as expected:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         opnsense.hhv3   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

But if I add in the following, the networking stops working after a little while:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.23       
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.254
        bridge_ports eth0    
        bridge_stp off      
        bridge_waitport 0 
        bridge_fd 0
```

Is the bridge interface taking over the eth0 interface completely? If so, how can I set up this to allow me to use the interface from the server and also from the future virtual machine(s) running on it? I also want the virtual machine(s) to be able to access the network and (preferably) be accessed from the server it is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meh, found the answer myself, partly with help from [Bridging ethernet interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41680/bridging-ethernet-interface)

Remove all settings for eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces and it all works

It is stated a bit convoluted in the description I was following since it is described in a new file ## make sure all config related to eth0 deleted ## - which of course was pointing to the entire netconfig, I read it just to be about /etc/network/interfaces.d/br0. - clear when you just understand it...

Comment: Yes, this is a bit surprising the first time you come across it ;-). See also [the instructions on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections).